# PHP custom session handler write parameter missing

Tags: php, oop, session

I am getting a weird error I haven't seen before when using a custom session handler in PHP (code below). When session_start() is called I get a Warning: Missing argument 2 for Session::write() on line 22 and a Notice: Undefined variable: data on line 25.

Line 22 is public function write($id, $data) and line 25 is where the data variable is used just below.

Can anyone see a mistake in my code?

Thanks

```
    class Session {

    private $db;
    private $expires_time;

    public function __construct($database, $expires_time) {
        $this->db = $database;
        $this->expires_time = $expires_time;
    }

    public function open($path, $name) {
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        return true;
    }

    public function write($id, $data) {
        $expires = time() + $this->expires_time;
        $query = $this->db->prepare('REPLACE INTO sessions (id, data, expires) VALUES (:id, :data, :expires)');
        return $query->execute(array(":id" => $id, ":data" => $data, ":expires" => $expires));
    }

    public function read($id) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id AND expires > :expires LIMIT 1');
        $query->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':expires' => time()));
        if($session = $query->fetch()) {
            return $session['data'];
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function destroy($id) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
        return $query->execute(array(':id', $id));
    }

    public function clean($max) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE expires < :expires');
        return $query->execute(array(':expires', $max));
    }

}
```

And the following code creates the object and sets the session save handler.

```
    $sess_expires_time = 3600;
$session = new Session($_DATABASE, $sess_expires_time);
session_set_save_handler(
    array($session, '_open'),
    array($session, '_close'),
    array($session, '_write'),
    array($session, '_read'),
    array($session, '_destroy'),
    array($session, '_clean')   
);
session_start();
```

Comment: Do you have a special version of PHP that hides the line numbers in error messages?

Comment: Okay, if now you could point out *which lines in your code* are 22 and 25 :)

Comment: Ha i'm having a bad night. See edit! Hopefully this time!

Answer (score 0):

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

PHP takes care of that already. Not that you write a second time (and then provoke the error in question). So remove that line.

For debugging purposes, enable xdebug on your development platform where you can provoke that error and/or php error configuration and *write stack traces to your error log*. Should give you an insight what's going on and especially when (you can normally only work reliably with the error log here, STDOUT is often closed when write is triggered in your save handler).

Additionally you do not do open/close tracking in your save handler. How can you know that you should write when the session is closed?

Also your session handler does not deal with session names. You should make this a bit more flexible, e.g. when switching sessions. If switching sessions is not intended, you should bail out with an exception, not that you silently kick your session save handler class out of the workflow unnoticed.

Comment: I removed the line (and have edited the code above). I also turned on xdebug. The code is throwing a warning because the variable $data is being passed to write() as undefined. However, this causes the code to  blow up and it won't save anything into the session after that.

Comment: Looks like  `$_SESSION` has been removed. Scan through your code if there is something like `unset($_SESSION);` or `$_SESSION = NULL;`. Replace with `$_SESSION = array();` if the intend is to clear session vars.

Comment: There definitely isn't anything like that in my code. I have edited the code above to include where the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Problem discovered. Stupid stupid stupid.

I had the wrong order of methods in the session_set_save_handler and was calling write and read in the wrong order.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Good you found it, take care :) I normally add a register function to the object itself.

Comment: Cheers hakre - I am re-working the code using your suggestions above.